# Convert std::string to boost::asio::streambuf

Tags: c++, boost

How do I convert the `std::string`  to `boost::asio::streambuf`?
Any lead is appreciated.

Initially I used `boost::asio::read_until(pNetworkConnector->getSocket(), response, "\r\n");` which initialized `boost::asio::streambuf response` and I converted it to underlying stream i.e.

```
boost::asio::streambuf* responsePointer = &response;
iResponseStream.rdbuf(responsePointer);
```

But now I directly get a `std::string` using curl like this

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

and used it as

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
```

How can I convert `std::string` to `boost::asio::streambuf` or `std::streambuf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code shows how to convert between `std::string` and `boost::asio::streambuf`, see it [online at ideone](https://ideone.com/5Ce9oy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>

int main()
{
   /* Convert std::string --> boost::asio::streambuf */
   boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
   std::iostream os(&sbuf);
   std::string message("Teststring");
   os << message;

   /* Convert boost::asio::streambuf --> std::string */
   std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&sbuf)),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```